# Busy Wait with Threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Basically, I need to busy wait until some html appears on a web page. I have created the following code to busy wait for me:

```
public void ExecuteBusyWaitThreads()
    {

        foreach (Canidate canidate in allCanidates)
        {
            Thread newThread = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                BusyWait(canidate);
            });

            newThread.Start();
        }
    }

    public bool BusyWait(Canidate canidate)
    {
        //hit that url, and wait for the claim all button to appear
        string page = null;
        while (found == false)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = Canidate.GetHTTPRequest(canidate.URL);
            //make sure we add the authentication cookes to the request
            request = Canidate.AddCookiesToRequest(request, canidate.GetCookies());
            page = new Canidate().GetPage(request);
            if (page.ToLower().Contains("claim all"))
            {
                found = true;
                NotifyAllThreads();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So, if I had 8 `canidates`, it would spawn off 8 threads, each of which is looking for `claim all` to appear on the web page. `found` is a global variable. Once one of the threads finds `claim all`, they all should bail.

I have a couple questions about this approach. First off, its it a good approach. Second, will each thread get its own "copy" of the busy wait function. By that I mean, can one thread preempt another and change the data in that function, or do they each get a copy of the variables declared inside the function. Note that both of these functions are inside the same object.

Comment: Valid technical question but looks like an attempt to cheat at poker or an auction.

Answer (score 5):

Before I answer your questions I have to point out that you have committed the egregious act of [closing over the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

> First off, its it a good approach.

No, not really. Creating threads arbitrarily is usually not a good idea. It is better to use thread pooling techniques. This can be done with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` or the `Task` class.

> Second, will each thread get its own "copy" of the busy wait function.
>   By that I mean, can one thread preempt another and change the data in
>   that function, or do they each get a copy of the variables declared
>   inside the function.

Each running instance of `BusyWait` will get its own copy of all local variables (ie. `page` and `request`). Since `found` is declared (presumably anyway) in a non-local scope then it will be shared among all running instances of `BusyWait`. As a consequence your current reads and writes to `found` are not thread-safe since there are no synchronization mechanisms in place.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. You may have solved another bug that I was seeing. Just so I understand the article correctly. In my foreach loop, I need to create a new variable that holds the canidate, and then pass this to the BusyWait funtion?

Comment: Good catch, I completely missed it. (The Homer is nice but may be considered over the top).

Comment: @user489041: That is correct. Closures capture *variables* not *values*. The `foreach` construct in its current form creates a single *variable* for the entirety of the loop. That is why you need to create a separate *variable* on your own to get this to work right. C# 5.0 will change the behavior of the `foreach` construct to automatically create a separate *variable* on each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

> Second, will each thread get its own "copy" of the busy wait function

Each thread will execute the function with it's own stack space, so that means that any variable that is local inside your function will belong to the thread it's being run on.  If you have a global variable, like your `found` variable being altered inside the function, you need to setup a synchronization mechanism so that no access to it occurs from multiple threads at the same time, as this will result in hard to find bugs and a lot of horrors you don't ever want to imagine going through!

Answer (score 2):

All threads get their own copies of the local variables (only `string page` in  this case).

Your shared `found` variable should be declared as volatile

This is a rare situation where a call to `Thread.Sleep()` might do some good. Insert a little breather between calls to the same site.

Comment: I actaully thought about doing that. However, could you elaborate on the benefits of adding a Thread.Sleep(). My application is actually in a race against others. It is very important that it detects the "claim all" button first. Would adding a Thread.Sleep() help or hurt this situation? Thanks

Comment: A short Sleep() will relieve the rest of your system and make processing the 8 tasks more equal. But to be competitive up to the very last ms, don't Sleep().

Answer (score 2):

Each thread does run with its own copy of the variables.

However I would modify my appoarch sightly.  Using the variable found is not thread safe.  It is possible that more than one thread will be changing found at a time.  It is also very possible that one thread will be reading it while the other is writing it.  The `[lock][1]` could avoid this.

The better way to solve this problem is to use the [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx).  This way you don't really have to worry about locking and you can build in a sleep or a time out so if 'claim-all' does not appear you threads will not run longer than you wish.

```
internal class ExampleOnExecute
{
    private static EventWaitHandle _stopEvent;

    public static EventWaitHandle StopEvent
    {
        get { return _stopEvent ?? (_stopEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset)); }
    }

    public static void SpinOffThreads(IEnumerable<object> someCollection)
    {
        foreach(var item in someCollection)
        {
            // You probably do not want to manualy create a thread since these ideally would be small workers
            // and action BeingInvoke runs in the ThreadPool
            Action<object> process = BusyWait;

            process.BeginInvoke(item, null, null);
        }
    }

    private static void BusyWait(object obj)
    {
        // You can wait for however long you like or 0 is not waiting at all
        const int sleepAmount = 1;

        //     Blocks the current thread until the current instance receives a signal, using
        //     a System.TimeSpan to specify the time interval.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   timeout:
        //     A System.TimeSpan that represents the number of milliseconds to wait, or
        //     a System.TimeSpan that represents -1 milliseconds to wait indefinitely.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the current instance receives a signal; otherwise, false.
        while (!StopEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(sleepAmount)))
        {
            // Do you work here
            var foundIt = DidIFindIt();

            if (foundIt)
            {
                // Signal all threads now to stop working we found it.
                StopEvent.Set();
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool DidIFindIt()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

[Here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) is an excellent *FREE* book on [threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).