# Closing over the Loop Variable in C#

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, syntactic-sugar

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622664/busy-wait-with-threads) post, I was told that the following section of code suffered from "the egregious act of closing over the loop variable."

```
    foreach (Canidate canidate in allCanidates)
    {
        Thread newThread = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            BusyWait(canidate);
        });

        newThread.Start();
    }
```

I switched it to this:

```
foreach (Canidate canidate in allCanidates)
        {
            var can = canidate;
            Thread newThread = new Thread(delegate()
            {                 
                BusyWait(can);
            });

            newThread.Start();
        }
```

But my boss keeps insisting that it will suffer from the same issues. I used [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) link to try to solve this issue. Can someone help me to correctly solve the issue so that my code will execute correctly. this issue is all new to me, and I am not sure I full understand it.

Comment: Your boss is wrong.

Comment: And has pointy hair.

Comment: Can anyone explain why that is? Im not sure I fully understand it. What exactly is the difference between the two, becuase to me, they seem like they are doing the exact same thing. However, when I run it, I know that they are not.

Comment: Your link from Eric Lippert's blog is one of the best sources.

Comment: If Eric Lippert can't convince your boss, then there's no point in arguing with him(your boss).  Just make the change, and show him that it works (or have your boss read that article?)

Comment: My Boss read the article, and said that, "that wasn't the problem" with the code.

Comment: @user489041: _"Can anyone explain"_:Because actually the `foreach` variable is declared outside of the loop. Hence your first loop uses always the same  whereas your second is  using a separate variable in each iteration.

Comment: @siyw What are you trying to do?

Comment: @L.B apologies, not sure what the hell went on there.

Comment: If you go to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/02/29/the-c-5-0-beta-release-is-now-available.aspx and look for the part of the comment that says "We've also ... fixed the semantics of closures in foreach loops", it looks like you can wait until C# 5 and not have to make any changes!

Comment: @user489041, Try to assign `can = null` before end of the loop in the second example. The issue is the delegate will use the value of `can` at the moment of execution. So while your code is correct now, same potential issue is there for future waiting for someone to do something with that local variable.

Answer (score 4):

Closing over variables that later change values is what is causing the problem.

- `candidate` changes every "lap" around the loop and *will* cause problems.
- `can` is newly created every "lap" around the loop, never changes, and *won't* cause problems.

Comment: So it fails because since candidate changes every "lap" around, that when the thread actually executes, it could be whatever value candidate is currently. And since the loop most likely finished before the thread starts, it is usually the last item in the candidate list?

Comment: @user489041 Exactly, it will get the current value, not the value it had when it was wrapped. A non changing variable will keep its value (by definition) and not cause problems, that's why creating a new variable in the loop will solve the situation, it will go out of scope and be created again instead of changed.