# Can somebody explain this odd behavior when working with ThreadPool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

## The Code

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public delegate void LoadingProgressCallback(double PercentComplete,string ItemName);
public delegate void LoadCompleteCallback(int ItemID, string ItemName);

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LoadTest loadTest = new LoadTest();
        loadTest.LoadItems(args);
    }
}

public class LoadTest
{       
    ManualResetEvent resetEvent;
    int numThreads = 0;

    public LoadTest()
    {}

    public void LoadItems(string[] Items)
    {
        numThreads = 0;
        resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        foreach(string item in Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Adding {0} to ThreadPool",item);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
            (
                delegate
                {
                    Load(item, this.progCall, this.compCall);
                }
            );
            numThreads++;

            Thread.Sleep(100);//Remove this line

        }
        resetEvent.WaitOne();
    }

    public void progCall(double PercentComplete, string ItemName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: is {1}% Complete [THREAD:{2}]",ItemName,PercentComplete.ToString(),Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
    }
    public void compCall(int ItemID, string ItemName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: is Complete",ItemName);
        numThreads--;
        if(numThreads == 0)
        {
            resetEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    public void Load(string Item, LoadingProgressCallback progressCallback, LoadCompleteCallback completeCallback)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loading: {0} [THREAD:{1}]",Item,Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());

        for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            if(progressCallback != null)
            {
                progressCallback((double)i, Item);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        if(completeCallback != null)
        {
            completeCallback(0,Item);
        }
    }
}
```

## Observation

If I run this program from the command line, like this...

`>TheProgram item1 item2`

The output will look like this.

> Adding item1 to ThreadPool
>   Loading: item1 [THREAD:3]
>   item1: is 0%
>   Complete [THREAD:3]
>   Adding item2 to ThreadPool
>   Loading: item2 [THREAD:4]
>   item2: is 0% Complete [THREAD:4]
>   item1: is 1% Complete [THREAD:3]
>   item2: is 1% Complete [THREAD:4]
>   item1: is 2% Complete [THREAD:3]
>   item2: is 2% Complete [THREAD:4]

However, if I remove this line.

`Thread.Sleep(100);//Remove this line`

From the `LoadItems` method, the output looks like this.

> Adding item1 to ThreadPool
>   Adding item2 to ThreadPool
>   Loading: item2 [THREAD:4]
>   Loading: item2 [THREAD:3]
>   item2: is 0% Complete [THREAD:4]
>   item2: is 0% Complete [THREAD:3]
>   item2: is 1% Complete [THREAD:4]
>   item2: is 1% Complete [THREAD:3]
>   item2: is 2% Complete [THREAD:3]
>   item2: is 2% Complete [THREAD:4]

## The Question

It seems as though two threads are being used, though they both seem to be acting on the same data. Why does the code behave this way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're closing over the loop variable, which gives you an unexpected result. Try this instead:

```
foreach(string item in Items)
{
    string item2 = item;
    Console.WriteLine("Adding {0} to ThreadPool", item2);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
    (
        delegate
        {
            Load(item2, this.progCall, this.compCall);
        }
    );
    numThreads++;

    Thread.Sleep(100);//Remove this line

}
```

**References**

- [Closing over the Loop Variable in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626051/closing-over-the-loop-variable-in-c-sharp)
- [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)

Comment: +1 Good catch, I stared at the code for 5 minutes and simply didn't see it.

Comment: +1. There must be at least 500 questions related to this issue alone. I have answered a few so far.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that immediately comes to mind looking at the code is lack of use of `Interlocked`.

You have to use [it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) otherwise you will see strange errors and behaviours.

So instead of

```
numThreads++;
```

Use:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref numThreads);
```

Comment: Would I then call `Interlocked.Decrement(ref numThreads)` in the `compCall` method?