# Set different objects to Timer.Elapsed

Tags: c#, .net

I want to assign different timer to each object.

Each object contains Timer as class member.

So that is what I've tried:

```
private void EntityTimeElapsed(object sender, MyEntity myEntity)
{

}

foreach (MyEntity myEntity in entities)
{
  myEntity.timer.AutoReset = true;
  myEntity.timer.Elapsed += (sender, arguments) => this.EntityTimeElapsed(sender, myEntity);
  myEntity.timer.Start();
}
```

The problem is that 'EntityTimeElapsed' is being hit with the last "MyEntity" object, and not the one I've wanted.

How can I fix it ?

**UPDATE:**

I'm currently using .Net 4.0

Comment: What version of framwowrk you're using?

Comment: see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.asps.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992866/can-somebody-explain-this-odd-behavior-when-working-with-threadpool?lq=1

Comment: You say "not the one you've wanted" but you don't say *which* is the one you want or *why* you expect that it's going to be triggered first. Can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (MyEntity myEntity in entities)
{
    var myEntity2 = myEntity ;

    myEntity2.timer.AutoReset = true;
    myEntity2.timer.Elapsed += (sender, arguments) => this.EntityTimeElapsed(sender, myEntity2);
    myEntity2.timer.Start();
```

}

There http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx explain why you always see in your lambda always the last value of myEntity.

Comment: Can you please explain your code? Why you're doing "var myEntity2 = myEntity" ?

Comment: The link explains it. Your lambda _captures_ the reference (`myEntity`) which subsequently changes. This was your problem. Now, the solution is to capture a variable that isn't re-assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Because the anonymous/lambda method uses the variable entity from the enumerator which changes. You have to create a local member/variable first and use that one in your lambda method.

```
foreach (MyEntity myEntity in entities)
{
  MyEntity backup = myEntity;
  myEntity.timer.AutoReset = true;
  myEntity.timer.Elapsed += (sender, arguments) => this.EntityTimeElapsed(sender, backup);
  myEntity.timer.Start();
}
```