# Treeview Async Problems

Tags: c#, multithreading, treeview

I am having a problem with a treeview where I try to add a subnode based upon the Node.Text Index (I have also tried this based upon the int index - to no avail). This works wonderfully when ran synchronously. However I run the exact same thing Async (backgroundWorker) it throws an unhandled ArgumentOutOfRange Exception. Another odd part is that I've attempted to catch this Exception in two different areas. see code:

```
 using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key))
        {
            int x = 0;
            foreach (string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
                {
                    foreach (string a in (string[])subkey.GetValue("Users", ""))
                    {
                        User u = new User(a);
                        usrs.addUser(new User(a));
                        wgs.addUserToWorkgroup(subkey_name, a);
                        usrs.AddWorkGroupToUser(subkey_name, a);
                        int trycount = 0;
                    TryAgain:
                        try
                        {
                            //here is where the exception occurs
                            ExecuteSecure(() => treeView1.Nodes[subkey_name].Nodes.Add(a, a));
                        }
                        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)//This does not catch it.
                        {
                            trycount++;
                            if (trycount < 100)
                            {
                                goto TryAgain; //b/c I cannot catch it this never happens...
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

                x++;
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
                //As you can see I've tried to let the tread sleep to resolve this 
                //- it will get a little farther but still eventually bomb out.
            }
        }
```

Here is the ExecuteSecure code [(https://stackoverflow.com/a/8021020/1387186)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8021020/1387186)

```
 private void ExecuteSecure(Action a)
    {
        o = new object();
        try
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                lock (o)
                {
                    BeginInvoke(a);
                }
            }
            else
                a();
        }
        catch (Exception) //again **sigh** this does not catch the error
        { }
```

Comment: Another victim of closing over the for loop variable.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing over the Loop Variable in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626051/closing-over-the-loop-variable-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Which goal did you try to achive by lock(o)?

Comment: It seems like an attempt to prevent concurrent action execution. It didn't work because you use a local object to lock.

Comment: your lock(o) before `BeginInvoke` is pointless, o is a new value (i.e. nothing else could ever use it to lock) *and* `BeginInvoke` returns immediately... which is why you don't catch anything.

Comment: Yeah the lock isnt doing anything I get that - I just havent removed it or changed its scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems.

- You are closing over the loop variable.
- Your lock is pointless because you use a *different* instance each time.
- Your lock is pointless because no other threads compete for it.
- Your new solution of using `Invoke` cause the UI and worker threads to ping-pong back and forth and as such your worker thread now became useless.

Anyone who monitors my answers on here knows how I feel about these marshaling techniques (like `Invoke`). It can be (and usually is) the worst method of updating the UI. In fact, it is so overused that it has gotten to the point where I think it can be considered a form of [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

What you should do is have your worker thread publish the data required to update the `TreeView` into a queue and then have your UI thread pull it out via a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` on an interval that works best for you. Here is what it would look like.

```
public class YourForm : Form
{
  private sealed class YourData
  {
    public string SubKeyName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
  }

  private ConcurrentQueue<YourData> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<YourData>();

  private void StartTreeViewUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(WorkerThread);
    TreeViewUpdateTimer.Enabled = true;
  }

  private void TreeViewUpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    // Update in batches of 100 (or whatever) so that the UI stays
    // responsive.
    treeView1.BeginUpdate();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      YourData value = null;
      if (queue.TryDequeue(value) && value != null)
      {
        treeView1.Nodes[value.SubKeyName].Nodes.Add(value.Value, value.Value)
      }
      else
      {
        // We're done.
        TreeViewUpdateTimer.Enabled = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    treeView1.EndUpdate();
  }

  private void WorkerThread()
  {
    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key))
    {
      foreach (string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
      {
        using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
        {
          foreach (string a in (string[])subkey.GetValue("Users", ""))
          {
            User u = new User(a);
            usrs.addUser(new User(a));
            wgs.addUserToWorkgroup(subkey_name, a);
            usrs.AddWorkGroupToUser(subkey_name, a);
            var data = new YourData();
            data.SubKeyName = subkey_name;
            data.Value = a;
            queue.Enqueue(data);
          }
          queue.Enqueue(null); // Indicate that queueing is done.
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont believe I actually am closing over the variable here, I say that based upon what I've read here:
["can is newly created every "lap" around the loop, never changes, and won't cause problems"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9626173/1387186)

Nonetheless your idea seems the best choice. I've been bugging myself to come up with a messaging system that I can reuse and learn with, but I just havent prioritized it. Perhaps you'll be my muse to do things the correct way. Could you offer any good jumping off points?

Answer (score 0):

In case the comments are obvious, do this:

```
 var uncapturedSubKey_name = subkey_name;
 ExecuteSecure(() => treeView1.Nodes[uncapturedSubKey_name].Nodes.Add(a, a));
```

The lambda is capturing the the other variable and isn't executing until after the loop is done (i.e. the last subkey_name...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this like so:

By changing the BeginInvoke() to Invoke()
  I also changed the scope of O so it actually locks.

```
private void ExecuteSecure(Action a)
{

    try
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            lock (o)
            {
                Invoke(a);
            }
        }
        else
            a();
    }
    catch (Exception) //again **sigh** this does not catch the error
    { }
```