# Thread.Start vs Action in ThreadStart

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, delegates

I have faced this problem while changing a code block.

```
List<Entity> entities = new List<Entity>();
//Some values added to the list ....

foreach(var entity in entities)
{
  Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SomeMethod));
  th.Start(entity);
}
```

SomeMethod is taking Entity and changing on it. somthing like

```
private void SomeMethod(Entity entity)
{
  //Some operation on entity
}
```

This is a .NET 2.0 code, while changing it to 4.0 I did a small change i.e.

```
foreach(var entity in entities)
{
  Thread th = new ThreadStart(() => SomeMethod(entity));
  th.Start();
}
```

This is not working, from error it looks like entity variable getting changed between threads and resulting some null reference exception. I havnt changed anything else, as soon as code reverted to the previous way, it is fine. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: This can't be the actual code because `ThreadStart` is a delegate and is not convertible to a `Thread`. However if you closing over the loop variable `entity` then you will likely run into issues.

Comment: You are correct, I have corrected it now.

Comment: You are correct, I have corrected it now at both places. Can you please have a look now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing over the Loop Variable in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626051/closing-over-the-loop-variable-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Tried that with ... var obj = entity and then passing it as SomeMethod(obj) .. but no luck ... It looks like all threads are not getting started with proper entity object.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use a new local variable in such a way:

```
foreach(var entity in entities)
{
  var copy = entity;
  Thread th = new ThreadStart(() => SomeMethod(copy));
  th.Start();
}
```

The approach with a new variable will not work if you introduce the variable in such a way

```
Thread th = new ThreadStart(() => {var copy = entity; SomeMethod(copy)) };
```

since that code will still capture the loop variable that is changed in each iteration of the loop.

**Also please note** that you can get the error you described **if the entities collection contains the same element twice** (that is two references to the same `Entity` object). Please make sure that it's not the case.